Switch from s3 standard class to intelligent tiering
I want to completely move from standard class to intelligent tiering in s3 (change the class for older objects and the new class should be used for the objects created in future too). After some research, i came across lifecycle rules, i created one and how much i understood, it only applies to the new objects created.
How to completely change the class for older objects too without creating any copy of the older objects (as from s3 console, there is an option to switch but that creates a copy of the objects).

You understood wrong. Lifecycle rules are applied to all the objects in the bucket and you can use it to move all your objects to other tier

@Caldazar lifecycle policy rules can be scoped to specific key prefixes, tags, or object size.

@Caldazar by default it applies to all the objects, but "all the objects" are the new created objects or we can also apply some filters too like prefix etc, but in both the cases, i think it applies to the newly created objects only not the already present ones. How to completely switch to intelligent tier?

@jarmod correct, I was typing in a hurry. Rules can be scoped as you said. What I meant is, it's not applied only to new objects, but existing ones as well

Yes. the lifecycle policy applies to existing and new objects. I think it would be helpful if you could clarify what your actual question is here.

@jarmod my actual question is, how to completely switch from standard to intelligent tiering. By completely, i mean it should apply to all the existing objects as well as the objects created in future. And standard class shouldnot be used at any step.
Also, if it is only the lifecycle rule, then please share the steps to do so ( though i created one and it has been nearly 3-4 days now, but no changes reflected ), maybe i missed something.

Oh wait wait, i can see the changes in my files, there are some new files as well as some old files which have shifted to intelligent tiering, meaning, it is working, thank you all for your responses.

S3 Lifecycle object transitions and object expirations are asynchronous operations. There is typically a delay between the time that the objects become eligible for expiration or transition and the time that they are actually transitioned or expired.

@jarmod as the transition takes some time, so standard class is always used. My main goal here is to use intelligent tiering to reduce costs, as standard class is still being used, does that mean it will have extra charges for that too?

The lifecycle documentation is helpful: billing changes are applied as soon as the object becomes eligible for the lifecycle action, even though the transition or expiration may actually happen later.
